# Java compiler for android phones

Tags: java, c++, android, compiler-construction

I have done a little googling but not found too much info on the subject so im asking here,

Does any body know of a phone based java or c/c++ compiler so a dev could effectively use his phone to do some preliminary dev work (or just to play around with when bored on the tube :))

Comment: You want to write apps for the phone on the phone itself?

Comment: At first I thought you want to create an app and asking which phone you should buy. :)

Comment: OK, so you asked about this WAY back in June, 2011 - a year and a half ago. I'm curious if it's worked out for you. But I also want to point out that there's finally something of a community trying to form around Terminal-IDE. Check out http://Terminal-IDE.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found terminal-ide ( https://market.android.com/details?id=com.spartacusrex.spartacuside&hl=en), and it is awesome if you are not afraid of the command line. Onboard java compiler.

Comment: Thanks! i think this is as close as it will get for the near future!

Answer (score 3):

If you want just to play around, please have a look at [IdeDroid](http://www.idedroid.com/) - the Android client for the ideone service.

Answer (score 1):

Try ASE aka "Android Scripting" http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/ (ok - it's not a java or c++ compiler but you can edit and run stuff directly on your phone and have pretty much full access to the APIs)

Comment: ASE is cool, but Roooss specifically says "java or c/c++", neither of which are (currently!) supported by ASE.

Comment: Yeah - I edited my comment when I read his specs in more detail ... but ...as an open minded dev, I often niavely restrict by language and then someone suggests "Just use xyz! if you can in abc-lang" and after looking into it, it's often exactly what I need. I'm just trying to get more people to use python I guess 8-)

Answer (score 0):

Try Multilang Compiler...It support C/C++ https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.us.onlinecompilr

Answer (score 0):

Just download an app named andosbox . Then download Turbo C++ and extract it. Place the TC folder in external SD card. Just start andosbox. Move to the TC directory by using cd command. Move to BIN . then just execute the file TC by just  tc command .  Then turbo c++ will start.  You can do any complex program in it just like PC.

But if you want more sophisticated use of compilers . I would recommend you to use

1. Limbo PC emulator(if no root access is present):
       Now download any Linux distribution in ISO format. Then boot form the location in SD card after configuring the virtual machine. Then you can install any compiler in it like computer.You can also install Windows in it if you get the proper windows version(as no site will give you that due to legal trouble)
2. Linux Deploy(Root access /Jail broken):
         Install the app and set the graphics mode to either vnc ( then download VNC viewer) or ssh ( then download ssh client)
   The app will automatically download and install the Linux distribution image and you can access it using vnc viewer by accessing loop back address 127.0.0.1 and the specified port...
3. It is very easy option for non rooted decides:
        Install an app named termux. It is in google play store. It will give a light weight Linux essence . you can install most of the Linux based c,c++,java compilers in it...